# XQuery: select distinct nodes

Tags: xml, xquery, distinct-values

I am trying to learn XQuery and I haven't figured out how to select distinct teachers in the following xml file that I have made. I have looked up distinct-values() but it only seems to return a sequence of Strings only. If I want to run XQuery only without declaring functions such as functx:distinct-deep and functx:distinct-nodes from http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0015.html#c0053, is there a way I can select distinct teachers who have taught in both credit and non-credit courses in the same year from the xml file below? I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
<DB>
<credit>
<course_title>biology101</course_title>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <firstname>Amy</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Hanson</lastname>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Lee</lastname>
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <year>2013</year>
</credit>
<credit>
<course_title>chemistry101</course_title>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Richardson</lastname>
        <firstname>Rob</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Hanson</lastname>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <year>2013</year>
</credit>
<noncredit>
<course_title>physics101</course_title>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Hanson</lastname>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Head</lastname>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <year>2013</year>
</noncredit>
<noncredit>
<course_title>physics101</course_title>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Lee</lastname>
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Head</lastname>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <lastname>Hanson</lastname>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
    </teacher>
    <year>2013</year>
</noncredit>
</DB>
```

I used the XQuery below:

```
let $DB := doc("myDB.xml") /DB
let $credit_teacher := $DB/credit/teacher

for $noncredit_teacher in $DB/noncredit/teacher
where $DB/credit/year = $DB/noncredit/year
and $credit_teacher/lastname = $noncredit_teacher/lastname
and $credit_teacher/firstname = $noncredit_teacher/firstname
return $noncredit_teacher
```

But the duplicating teachers are returned:

```
<teacher>
  <lastname>Hanson</lastname>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
</teacher>
<teacher>
  <lastname>Lee</lastname>
  <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
</teacher>
<teacher>
  <lastname>Hanson</lastname>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
</teacher>
```

If I use distinct-values, a sequence of Strings is returned:
     HansonJohn LeeSandra

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to:

1. Find all the teachers that have taught in both credit and non-credit modules within the same year.
2. Filter those teachers so that they are distinct. I have used a tail-recursive function `local:distinct-teachers` to achieve this, that operates over the sequence of all teachers found in (1). It examines each teacher in turn and if it has not see it before, it adds it to an accumulator of `$distinct` teachers.

   ```
   declare function local:distinct-teachers($teachers as element(teacher)*, $distinct as element(teacher)*) as element(teacher)* {
     if(empty($teachers)) then
       $distinct
     else
       let $teacher := $teachers[1]
       return
         let $new-distinct := if($distinct/.[lastname eq $teacher/lastname]
             [firstname eq $teacher/firstname]
         ) then
             $distinct
         else
             ($teacher, $distinct)
         return
             local:distinct-teachers($teachers[position() gt 1], $new-distinct)
   };


   let $teachers :=
       let $credit-teachers := doc("myDB.xml")/DB/credit/teacher
       let $non-credit-teachers := doc("myDB.xml")/DB/noncredit/teacher
       return
           for $credit-teacher in $credit-teachers
           for $non-credit-teacher in $non-credit-teachers
           return
               $credit-teacher
                   [lastname eq $non-credit-teacher/lastname]
                   [firstname eq $non-credit-teacher/firstname]
                   [following-sibling::year eq $non-credit-teacher/following-sibling::year]
   return
       local:distinct-teachers($teachers, ())
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are already selecting the distinct nodes. The teacher nodes you are selecting are repeated in the source XML, and therefore have separate node identities.

You'll have to do some form of de-duplication based on the contents of the nodes. `functx:distinct-nodes()` and  `functx:distinct-deep` are good examples of that kind of de-duplication.

Comment: joemfb, thanks for your advice. I tried using functx:distinct-nodes() and functx:distinct-deep but still got the same results without any de-duplication. Do you know of other methods that I can try? Thank you once again.